# Ldap sync over SSL

Tags: ssl, sonarqube, ldap

I have a clean installation of

- SonarQube 9.9.2
- Oracle Linux 8.8
- Oracle DB 19c
- Appache Proxy

Everything works fine but but i can't provite ldaps conectivity. But it's work with ldap://ldap_url:389.
The Certificate has been added to trusted store i also checked network connetivity by port 636, i also have other service on this VM and there don't have issue or any other problems with ldaps conectivity(with same certificate).
Into log file it seems use the certificate. If anybody can help me.
My configuration:

`sonar.security.realm=LDAP sonar.log.level=DEBUG' ldap.url=ldaps://ldap_url:636 ldap.bindDn=user@domain ldap.bindPassword=user_password ldap.authentication=simple`
`ldap.user.baseDn=OU=Group,DC=domain,DC=com ldap.user.request=(&(objectClass=user)(sAMAccountName={0})) ldap.user.realNameAttribute=cn ldap.user.emailAttribute=mail`

And error from web.log file:
`WARN  web[][o.s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext] Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt:  org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:  Error creating bean with name 'jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader@5ffd2b27-org.sonar.server.ws.WebServiceEngine':  Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:  Error creating bean with name 'jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader@5ffd2b27-org.sonar.server.authentication.ws.AuthenticationWs':  Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:  Error creating bean with name 'jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader@5ffd2b27-org.sonar.server.authentication.ws.LoginAction':  Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:  Error creating bean with name 'jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader@5ffd2b27-org.sonar.server.authentication.CredentialsAuthentication':  Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 4; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:  Error creating bean with name 'jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader@5ffd2b27-org.sonar.server.authentication.LdapCredentialsAuthentication':  Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 3; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:  Error creating bean with name 'jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader@5ffd2b27-org.sonar.auth.ldap.LdapRealm':  Bean instantiation via constructor failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException:  Failed to instantiate [org.sonar.auth.ldap.LdapRealm]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is org.sonar.auth.ldap.LdapException:  LDAP realm failed to start: Unable to open LDAP connection ERROR web[][o.s.s.p.Platform] Background initialization failed. Stopping SonarQube org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name  'jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader@5ffd2b27-org.sonar.server.ws.WebServiceEngine':  Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0;  nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:  Error creating bean with name 'jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader@5ffd2b27-org.sonar.server.authentication.ws.AuthenticationWs':  Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:  Error creating bean with name 'jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader@5ffd2b27-org.sonar.server.authentication.ws.LoginAction':  Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:  Error creating bean with name 'jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader@5ffd2b27-org.sonar.server.authentication.CredentialsAuthentication':  Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 4; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:  Error creating bean with name 'jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader@5ffd2b27-org.sonar.server.authentication.LdapCredentialsAuthentication':  Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 3; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:  Error creating bean with name 'jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader@5ffd2b27-org.sonar.auth.ldap.LdapRealm':  Bean instantiation via constructor failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException:  Failed to instantiate [org.sonar.auth.ldap.LdapRealm]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is org.sonar.auth.ldap.LdapException:  LDAP realm failed to start: Unable to open LDAP connection`

Answer (score 0):

The problem was solved! I import CA root certificate in trusted store and connection to LDAP server was established over SSL.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).